# How can I get the text content of an anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I am using an anchor tag and have to access its content in jQuery. I have to access the 'text' from this. I have known about `$("#AnchorID").attr("href")` or something else but is there any way to grab the value ('text') of it?

```
<a href="">text</a>
```

Comment: Cannot understand why this question gotupvoted ,seems to be a perfect google search material.

Answer (score 6):

Use $("#AnchorID").text(),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nLh5K/)**

```
<a id="AnchorID" href="">text</a>
```

**To get the text**

```
textOfAnchor = $("#AnchorID").text();
```

**To change the text**

```
$("#AnchorID").text("new text");
```

**To get the html**

```
htmlOfAnchor = $("#AnchorID").html();
```